# Can I scroll splitted screens in Visual Studio in the same time?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to scroll **at the same time** splitted screens in Visual Studio (Vertically or Horizontally, dont really care)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible.

Here is the link to the [Microsoft connect suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115106/scrolling-simultaneously-in-a-split-window) (requires login).  It suggests that it may be possible to achieve the effect with a macro or an add-in.

(Here is a [duplicate question regarding VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606327/in-visual-studio-2008-is-it-possible-to-simultaneously-scroll-two-vertical-tab).)